# Testing with Rhino Mock throws an error

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks

Hello I am kind of a beginner level with TDD and using RhinoMocks for creating moqs in application.  I am trying to implement MVP pattern.

Here is my interface

```
public interface IView
{
   List<Bundle> DisplayList { get; set; }  
}
```

and my Presenter class

```
public class Presenter
{
    private IView View;
    public Presenter(IView view)
    {
        View = view;            
    }

    public void Bind()
    { 
        // I am creating a dummy list in MockDataLayer and SelectAll Method returns the whole list
        IDataLayer dsl=new MockDataLayer();
        View.DisplayList = dsl.SelectAll();
    } 
}
```

Below is my test class

```
public class PresenterTest 
{

    private IView _view;
    private Presenter _controller;

    [Test]
    public void View_Display_List()
    {
        //Arrange
        _view = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IView>();
        List<Bundle> objTest = new List<Bundle>();            
        _controller = new Presenter(_view);
        _view.Expect(v => v.DisplayList).Return(objTest);

        //Act
        _controller.Bind();

        //Assert
        _view.VerifyAllExpectations();
    }
}
```

When I execute my test, I recieve this error:

```
depaulOAR.PatchBundleTesting.Test.BundlePresenterTest.BundleView_Display_Bundle_List:
Rhino.Mocks.Exceptions.ExpectationViolationException : IBundleView.get_DisplayList(); Expected #1, Actual #0.
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

> **EDIT:** NOTE I am getting help from this link. Almost everything is
>   working except the test part. When I implement it on Web form, my
>   browser displays the list. But when I test the View it throws an error
>   http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2012/04/mvp-design-pattern-survival-kit.html
>
> Thanks **"Old Fox"** for your help. But now my issue is it's throwing a different error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize an expectation on the `IView.DisplayList`'s getter:

```
_view.Expect(v => v.DisplayList).Return(objTest);
```

The above line put's an expectation on the getter.

In the method under test you use the `IView.DisplayList`'s setter:

```
View.DisplayList = dsl.SelectAll();
```

I believes that the behavior you want to test is: "The items to display was set in the view". 
If so, your test should be something similar to:

```
[Test]
public void View_Display_List()
{
   //Arrange
   _view = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IView>();
   List<Bundle> objTest = new List<Bundle>();
   controller = new Presenter(_view);

   //Act
   _controller.Bind();

   //Assert
   CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(The same items MockDataLayerl.SelectAll() returns 
                                  ,_view.DisplayList );
}
```

**Edit:**

Verifies that something was assign to `View.DisplayList` is easier then the above example. 
You have to verify that `View.DisplayList` is not `null`:

```
[Test]
public void View_Display_List()
{
   //Arrange
   _view = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IView>();
   _view.Stub(x => x.Display List).Property Behavior();
   List<Bundle> objTest = new List<Bundle>();
   controller = new Presenter(_view);

   //Act
   _controller.Bind();

   //Assert
   Assert.IsNotNull(_view.DisplayList );
}
```

Comment: I would like to test that the View.DisplayList is not empty. It has the data what's been assigned to it.

Comment: @fais, because `View` is a mock, you only have to verify that `_view.DisplayList` is not null. See my edit.

Comment: When I changed my code like yours and when I execute it. I am getting a new error:
depaulOAR.PatchBundleTesting.Test.BundlePresenterTest.BundleView_Display_Bundle_List_Not_Empty:
  Expected: not null
  But was:  null
Although my list is not empty

Comment: @fais Because you use `GenerateMock` method instead of `GenerateStub` you need to specify `_view.Stub(x => x.Display List).Property Behavior();` in the arrange section. I updated my answer.

Comment: But why are you creating a Stub?

Comment: @fais I didn't create any `stub`, as I said take a look in my update. By default each property in `stub` behave as property. In `mock` by default each property returns the default value of the type, unless you use the extension method: `PropertyBehavior()`.